# 'defaults write com.google.Chrome PasswordManagerEnabled true' has no effect

Tags: macos, google-chrome, preferences, plist, defaults

'defaults write com.google.Chrome PasswordManagerEnabled' has no effect. Neither the contents of

`/Library/Managed Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist` nor that of 
`/Library/Managed Preferences/<username>/com.google.Chrome.plist` change.

And the corresponding Chrome feature "*Offer to save passwords*" also stays greyed out / disabled.

I also tried to apply defaults directly to the files

`/Library/Managed Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist` and 
`/Library/Managed Preferences/<username>/com.google.Chrome.plist`

using the command

`sudo defaults write /Library/Managed Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist PasswordManagerEnabled -bool true`,

also without success. Applying the command to the same plist file in the `/Library/Preferences/` folder changed the value, but did not activate the password manager in Chrome.

How can I fix this? Or: where else are these settings configured? Or generally, **how to I change Managed Preferences**?

**UPDATE:**

I succeeded to edit the plist files under `/Library/Managed Preferences/` using Plist Edit Pro. But that was cumbersome, since I needed to change file and folder permissions first (and restrict them again later). Also the changes get overwritten after reboot, so **still looking for a nice solution to change Managed Preferences**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to elaborate a little more, the following steps need to be taken:

1. Copy `/Library/Managed Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist` to a user-visible directory (e.g. `~/Downloads`)
2. Download Plist Edit Pro, open the file, set `PasswordManagerEnabled` to `YES` and save the file
3. Copy `~/Downloads/com.google.Chrome.plist` back to `/Library/Managed Preferences`
4. Change the owner of the file `sudo chown root:wheel com.google.Chrome.plist`
5. Re-read the preference cache `defaults read com.google.Chrome`
6. Restart Chrome, check that `chrome://policy` now lists your change correctly (alternatively hit "Reload policies" until it does
7. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome policies can be configured using configuration profiles on macOS. Using configuration profiles also mark the policies as 'mandatory' in `chrome://policy`, meaning they override policies set by an organization at the Google account level. You can find more details at Google's [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9020077), but I've included a example MCX configuration that's already been formatted as a .mobileconfig file, so it can be simply saved to a file, tweaked to your needs, and installed through Settings without needing any external tools. You can find a list of policies [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>com.google.Chrome</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Forced</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>mcx_preference_settings</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>PasswordManagerEnabled</key>
                                <true/>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
            <true/>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>MCXToProfile.7e2bec75-299e-44ff-b405-628007abffff.alacarte.customsettings.bdac4880-d25f-4cdd-8472-05473f005e7e</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.ManagedClient.preferences</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>bdac4880-d25f-4cdd-8472-05473f005e7e</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Included custom settings:
com.google.Chrome
</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Chrome Policies</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.google.Chrome</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadScope</key>
    <string>Users</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>7e2bec75-299e-44ff-b405-628007abffff</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```