# Unable to pick settings in us.zoom.config.plist

Tags: macos, plist, mdm, configuration-profiles, zoom.app

I want to configure Zoom’s setting by pushing the plist file to the device from MDM.

After pushing the customized us.zoom.config.plist to my macOS device through MDM, I am able to find the plist file over /Library/Managed Preferences folder, but Zoom’s default behavior doesn’t change at all.

I tried to restart my machine, reinstall the Zoom app, push different plist content, and none of these helped me to achieve my goal. Would you let me know if I missed anything?

I also include the plist content below, please let me know if the format has any issues. Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>us.zoom.config.plist</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>us.zoom.config.F9953132-51DD-405B-9989-595CEF531A17</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>us.zoom.config</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>F9953132-51DD-405B-9989-595CEF531A17</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ZDisableVideo</key>
            <true/>
            <key>zDisableChat</key>
            <true/>
                <key>NoFacebook</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NoGoogle</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>us.zoom.config.plist</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>Wills-Macbook-Pro.F7329566-3114-452D-AF7C-3F03D825745E</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>35B0FD44-754C-4162-86BB-51B34A78110s5</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can install us.zoom.config.plist I attached above to /Library/Managed Preferences and watch if your Zoom app won’t turn on the camera automatically, disable the chat function, and disable FB/Google login.

Comment: The defaults database design requires you to push a script to write the changes - [not just deploy a file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436766/5472) that contains remnants (after effects) of what used to persist to disk once a `defaults write` command runs. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html Not all preferences are stored in files. [Zoom support might be needed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436766/5472) for this . [other tips here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402004/5472)